# How to run a subprocess on flask

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I currently run a flask app which creates a docker file for the user after sign up, how can I use a subprocess to fire up the **docker-compose up -d** process in the background I created a function start() which I call after a user clicks the submit button on my sign up form

```
command = 'docker-compose up -d'

def  start(command):
   subprocess.run(shlex.split(command), cwd=dir, check=True)
```

But I have noticed the signup doesn't work because it's waiting for the process to complete in the background, what I  want is for the user to complete the form and  then when the user clicks on the signup button it should call the start() function and then display my thank you page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the subprocess docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), run will wait for command to complete, then return a CompletedProcess instance. If you want to get around that, you should give it its own thread, which will allow the Flask request to finish (and your user to get the thank you page.

```py
import threading

def start(command):
   subprocess.run(shlex.split(command), cwd=dir, check=True)

@app.route('/register')
def register():
   ...
   thread = threading.Thread(target=start, args=('docker-compose up -d',))
   thread.start()
   return jsonify(msg='success'), 200
```